Помогите убрать ошибку скрипта
Как убрать это сообщение об ошибке

Я нашел папку с скриптом удалил её - не помогло

Вам надо найти "процесс", который пытается запустить файл, указанный на скриншоте. Посмотрите в момент ошибки в список запущенных процессов и поищите там vbs или cmd скрипты

этого скрипта нет. В планировщике заданий тоже ничего нет похожего
